# Hadoop 2.2.0 ResourceManager fails to bind to port 8088

Tags: apache, ubuntu, hadoop

I have been successfully running Hadoop version 2.2.0 on Ubuntu for a few weeks now. My previous experience was on 1.0.1. I am running Ubuntu 13.10 with a fresh install and build-essential installed along with a manually installed Hadoop environment. This Ubuntu box also has a LAMP environment as well that is running successfully. I had started with wordcount and have built out the pattern matching functionality beyond the examples. This all compiles and executes as expected. However I have one problem that has recently developed. I can't get the ResourceManager to successfully bind to 8088 any longer.

Nothing has changed in the yarn-site.xml file.

```
<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
    <value>superghdp220:8088</value>
</property>
```

The Hostname comes back correctly and my IP address checks out in ifconfig and the hosts file matches that IP address.

Apache is running on port 80 and returns the "It Works!" banner.

The output of jps is below

```
hduser@superghdp220:/usr/local/hadoop$ jps
19876 NameNode
20741 Jps
19997 DataNode
20175 SecondaryNameNode
20479 NodeManager
```

The output of `sudo netstat -an | grep ':8088'` returns NULL

The output of `sudo netstat -a -t --numeric-ports -p` return all bound ports, but 8088 is not on the list.

Finally here is the useful last output lines of yarn-hduser-resourcemanager-superghdp220.log

```
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmcontainer.ContainerAllocationExpirer thread interrupted
2014-04-03 11:17:27,638 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager: Error starting ResourceManager
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: java.net.BindException: Problem binding to [superghdp220:8088] java.net.BindException: Address already in use; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/BindException
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.factories.impl.pb.RpcServerFactoryPBImpl.getServer(RpcServerFactoryPBImpl.java:139)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.ipc.HadoopYarnProtoRPC.getServer(HadoopYarnProtoRPC.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.ipc.YarnRPC.getServer(YarnRPC.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ClientRMService.serviceStart(ClientRMService.java:149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:193)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceStart(CompositeService.java:121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.serviceStart(ResourceManager.java:671)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:193)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.main(ResourceManager.java:872)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Problem binding to [superghdp220:8088] java.net.BindException: Address already in use; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/BindException
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:719)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server.bind(Server.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Listener.<init>(Server.java:534)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server.<init>(Server.java:2203)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.<init>(RPC.java:897)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server.<init>(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:505)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine.getServer(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:480)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Builder.build(RPC.java:742)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.factories.impl.pb.RpcServerFactoryPBImpl.createServer(RpcServerFactoryPBImpl.java:169)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.factories.impl.pb.RpcServerFactoryPBImpl.getServer(RpcServerFactoryPBImpl.java:132)
    ... 8 more
2014-04-03 11:17:27,655 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down ResourceManager at superghdp220/192.168.137.160
************************************************************/
```

Any insight or help is much appreciated.
Thanks for reading,
Pat

Comment: What is the value of : yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address?

Comment: That is not a property that I have set at the moment. I only have the above Property value for yarn.resourcemanager.address. I will try that property now. BTW, that wasn't a property value In the install directives I was using. However, I had Resource Manager Web UI up and running for a couple weeks when initially installed

Comment: yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address default value is 8088 which is what the value for yarn.resourcemanager.address is as per your configuration. http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml

Comment: You're correct, I made that change according to the yarn-common docs and it bound fine. It is working now, I just don't know why it was working earlier without this property set. Thanks,Pat

Answer (score 0):

8088 is default used by "yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address" (you can check this doc for more detailed: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml)

so you can try changing port in yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address or yarn.resourcemanager.address